# Phpmyadmin and mysql connection fails after docker-compose down and up again

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

This is my docker-compose.yml file to launch PMA and mysql:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
 
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    ports:
      - "64121:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootsecretpassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
      - MYSQL_USER=db-username
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=db-password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.1.2
    ports:
      - "64122:80"
    environment:
      - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=600 
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=800M
      - PMA_HOST=mysql_db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db


volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

`docker-compose up --build`

Then, I can reach `localhost:64122` to see PMA(phpmyadmin) and I can login using credentials and everything works fine, **But** after running `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up --build` I can't login to PMA and it says:

```
 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'SOME IP ADRESS' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

So, what happens during `down` and `up` in docker that makes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database user can connect only from localhost by default

```
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "db-username";
```

Update table:

```
GRANT ALL ON dbname.* to 'db-username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db-password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "db-username";
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a clue from your answer and this link https://serverfault.com/questions/793058/can-not-access-mysql-docker